# ¿Cómo borrar una fila en mysql por el número de fila?

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy creando un programa en Java donde el usuario pueda borrar una fila de una tabla mysql según el número de fila.

Por ejemplo, hay 50 filas en una tabla, y quiero borrar la fila 32, no encuentro una manera de hacerlo porque todos funcionan con where y una condicion, pero el usuario al borrar no ingresa una condición, solo elige la fila a eliminar.

Comment: Esa fila puede tener un campo que contenga el id y al darle click capturas el evento y mandas ese id al codigo que elimina, tendrias que subir codigo para que los usuarios se puedan guiar y ayudarte, asi como esta la pregunta solo puedo decirte eso

Comment: Es que la tabla en si no tiene un campo id, solo tiene 3, nombre apellido y fecha, entonces al mostrar en consola, va a salir 1.- 2.-, y la idea es no modificar la tabla pues me la pasaron y tengo que implementar el delete

Comment: Es que ahi tenes un problemos si pasas para borrar un valor concatenado entre nombre y apellido y tenes a 10 Juan Perez te los va a borrar a todos, como consejo te digo que agregues aunque sea un campo de identificador unico, no te digo el dni porque si la persona es extranjera e ingreso a la empresa con un dni y luego lo cambio te va a quedar dos veces la misma persona con distinto dni en el historico de gestiones que haya hecho ese usuario

Comment: Christian, si puedes modificar la tabla no dudes en hacerlo tal y como ha indicado @Juan. Esta tabla necesita una columna de identificación que sea única, puede ser por ejemplo un campo auto_increment. En la tabla pueden haber varios `José Pérez` y si ejecutas un `DELETE` basado en nombre y apellido te vas a llevar por delante a todos los `José Pérez` que haya, sin distinción. `[broma]`Sólo espero que el jefe no se llame así, porque lo vas a quitar de en medio y te van a despedir... `[/broma]`

Answer (score 1):

Aunque es cierto que los registros tendrían que tener una primary key, nadie te ha dado respuesta a tu pregunta. Si quieres eliminar una fila en concreto de una base de datos sql, simplemente usa LIMIT.

```
CREATE TABLE ejemplo (
  nombre varchar(20),
  apellido varchar(20),
  edad int                 
);
INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUES ("María", "Pérez", 12);
INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUES ("Juan", "González", 34);
INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUES ("Hugo", "López", 3);
```

Selecciona María:

```
SELECT * FROM ejemplo
LIMIT 0,0;
```

Selecciona Juan:

```
SELECT * FROM ejemplo
LIMIT 1,1;
```

Selecciona Hugo:

```
SELECT * FROM ejemplo
LIMIT 2,2;
```

Aquí te dejo el fiddle: 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6V6a8DKMjVMi63VcTKB2mn/0

Comment: Hagamos otras inserciones más: `INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUES ("Juan", "González", 35); INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUES ("Juan", "González", 36); INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUES ("Juan", "González", 37); INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUES ("Juan", "González", 38);` cuando ejecutes un `DELETE` sobre `Juan González`, ¿sabes lo que ocurrirá?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas mi respuesta para poder entenderla. No he dicho que ejecute un DELETE sobre Juan González, le he dicho que ejecute un SELECT para seleccionar la ROW que necesita, sin necesidad de tener una primary key. Después. elimina el resultset y no hay más. Da igual cuántos Juan González haya, sólo eliminara el que se encuentre en esa fila. Sé que no es lo más óptimo, pero es por lo que él está preguntando. De hecho, lo digo en la primera línea "Aunque es cierto que los registros tendrían que tener una primary key".

Comment: Pero es que no veo forma de saber cuál es el `Juan González` que va a eliminar dado que realmente **no existe un número de fila, es algo ficticio**.

Comment: Esos select con limit son perfectos para esa tabla y porque sabes quienes son los 3 usuarios, pero en una tabla con 300.000 usuarios donde muchos se llaman igual con mismo apellido te la debo tener que adivinar a quien eliminar, en un localhost de prueba te arriesgas no perdes nada, ya si es una nomina de una empresa donde trabajas.... te la debo

Comment: - Sé que las tablas han de tener PK.
- Sé que si haces DELETE WHERE... en una tabla sin PK donde todos los campos coinciden con más de 1 elemento, todos esos elementos se van a eliminar.
Partiendo de eso, continúo. El punto es muy claro: quiere eliminar por NÚMERO DE FILA. Entiende número de fila como el orden en que se muestran (que en caso de no hacer sortby se muestran por el orden en que se insertaron). Ya he dejado claro que no es lo óptimo, pero para su ejemplo y para lo que él pregunta, es válido, dado que responde a su pregunta.

Comment: Te doy una tabla con 10 Juan Perez sin ids, solo esos 10 registros donde 8 son asesores, 1 es gerente y 1 es director (eso lo sabes vos porque no esta definido ni hay relaciones en la tabla) y te pido que elimines a Juan Perez, a quien eliminas?

Comment: "Estoy creando un programa en Java donde el usuario pueda borrar una fila de una tabla mysql **según el número de fila**." Sin primary key, la solución que le he dado es buena. Que no se debería hacer así, estoy de acuerdo, YA LO HE DICHO EN PRIMERA INSTANCIA. Que es una solución a lo que pide, también. No voy a extenderme más porque estoy repitiéndome a mí misma y creo que ya lo he dejado bastante claro.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta este query

```
DELETE FROM nombre_tabla WHERE id=?;
```

La condicion es importante para saber que fila es la que de desea eliminar,

Answer (score 0):

lo que te ha comentado juan es correcto igual lo puedes eliminar así:

```
DELETE FROM nombre_tabla WHERE nombre = ? AND apellido = ? AND fecha = ?;
```

Aunque la lógica debería tener un id para mayo seguridad y eficiencia.

NOTA: si la fecha es `TIMESTAMP` puedes eliminar con esta pues es casi imposible que haya otra igual el el sql te quedaría:

```
DELETE FROM nombre_tabla WHERE fecha = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría ver el modelo de tu tabla para responderte con mayor claridad.

Entiendo que, por número de fila, te refieres al id autogenerado de cada registro en la tabla.

Por ejemplo, imaginemos esta tabla de ciudades:

```
ID  CITY    STATE   LAT_N   LONG_W
13  Phoenix AZ  33  112
44  Denver  CO  40  105
66  Caribou ME  47  68
```

A la hora de efectuar un borrado de una fila siempre trataremos de filtrar correctamente y para ello usaremos el identificador primario de la tabla (ID)

```
DELETE FROM cities WHERE id = 13;
```

Ejecutando esta sentencia SQL habremos eliminado el primer registro de la tabla. En algunos SGBD se permite borrar por el id de la fila misma, que sería el equivalente a la anterior query, estilo:

```
DELETE FROM cities WHERE rowid = 1;
```

De todas formas, esto no debe hacerse así.

En este caso, nos indicas que el usuario elige un campo que borrará. Aquí es donde tienes que indicar, a la hora de llamar a tu consulta sql, el valor del id a borrar.

1. Usuario elige registro a borrar
2. sistema recoge el id del registro seleccionado
3. sistema usa el id para lanzar la consulta de borrado
4. sistema avisa del éxito o fracaso del borrado

No sé cómo lo tienes montado así que agradecería que editaras la pregunta para ayudarte mejor.